# Two words with almost the same pronunciation

Tags: riddle, wordplay

First of all I'm a 9 letter word:

> 1. I mean the opposite of the anagram 'ELAPSING'.

Me,  I'm a 8 letter word:

> 2. I, having the same pronunciation of the first word(but there's a little pause after pronouncing the first two letters) , I can be grasped in the following clue: 'Unconscious of junk now in gardens keeping'.

What are these two words?

Comment: Be careful of homonyms in games intended for a global audience. Are you certain that these two words are pronounced the same as each other in every dialect?

Comment: @IanMacDonald From a British perspective I can't see any similarity in the pronunciation of the these two words! T_T

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all I'm a 9 letter word:

> **UNKNOWING**

I, having the same pronunciation of the first word(but there's a little pause after pronouncing the first two letters) , I can be grasped in the following clue: 'Unconscious of junk now in gardens keeping'.

> This is a cryptic clue: j**unk now in g**ardens

Me, I I'm a 8 letter word:

> **ANNOYING**

I mean the opposite of the anagram 'ELAPSING'.

> If you are annoying, you are certainly not *PLEASING**

Comment: Did you just edit your answer to include without explanation the word I found but leave the rest of it the same?

Comment: @Randal'Thor No, I found the rest of the answer - I just accidentally hit 'edit' first

Comment: Oh I see, and now it looks like my comment came after the rest of your edit :-/ And I edited my answer to the full solution (hat-tip to JMP) before seeing your full edit here.

Comment: Can confirm: these two words are _not_ homonyms.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Not for me, either, but they're [pretty close](https://rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=unknowing&typeofrhyme=sim&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y)

Answer (score 6):

The solution appears to be

> UNKNOWING and ANNOYING,

where the OP has mixed up the explanations for the two words.

The 9-letter word is clued by "*Unconscious of junk now in gardens keeping*":

> unconscious = UNKNOWING, and this word is contained in "j**unk now in g**ardens".

The 8-letter word is clued by the ELAPSING thing:

> ANNOYING is a synonym of PLEASING which is an anagram of ELAPSING.

Thanks to @JMP for getting the 8-letter word after I figured out the 9-letter one.

Comment: You've gotten the first one carry on trying...

Comment: @user11039033 I'm confused by the structure of the question. The word I've found is 9 letters but it's clued in the *second* clue (the one for the 8-letter word).

Comment: That is ANNOYING :{

Comment: @JMP Too late :P

Comment: @JMP Aha, nice one!

Comment: Yeah! It's 8 letter word.

Comment: Lol! Was it quite tricky? Anyway?

Comment: @user11039033 Would have been a great puzzle if you'd got the 9 and 8 the right way round :-P The cluing of the 9-letter word was very nice, although I wouldn't agree on the two words being homophones.

Answer (score 4):

The words might be

> **DEPRESSED** and **DEEP REST** (Maybe a compound word?)
>  I know the second one is a stretch

I mean the opposite of the anagram 'ELAPSING'.

> An opposite of PLEASING could be **DEPRESSED**

I can be grasped in the following clue: 'Unconscious of junk now in gardens keeping'.

> Something buried in a garden could be in a **DEEP REST**.

Thoughts

> I'm assuming a lot with this answer. It is a very big stretch, but it does work a little.

Comment: NB: There's a little pause after pronouncing the first two letters NOT words.

Comment: @user11039033, I understand that. The pause is in the first word. Like I said, I made assumptions while formulating my answer.

Comment: DEEP REST is two words.

Comment: @JMP, I agree. I couldn't do any better though. I thought it was pretty good for what it was and threw it up here.